# Password hashing in UWP

Tags: c#, hash, uwp

I have the following code in .net framework.

```
public string GetHashedPassword(string password, string salt)
    {
        byte[] saltArray = Convert.FromBase64String(salt);
        byte[] passArray = Convert.FromBase64String(password);
        byte[] salted = new byte[saltArray.Length + passArray.Length];
        byte[] hashed = null;

        saltArray.CopyTo(salted, 0);
        passArray.CopyTo(salted, saltArray.Length);

        using (var hash = new SHA256Managed())
        {
            hashed = hash.ComputeHash(salted);
        }

        return Convert.ToBase64String(hashed);
    }
```

I'm trying to create an equivalent in .net core for a UWP application. Here's what I have so far.

```
public string GetHashedPassword(string password, string salt)
  {
        IBuffer input = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(password + salt, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
        var hashAlgorithm = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithmNames.Sha256);
        var hash = hashAlgorithm.HashData(input);

        //return CryptographicBuffer.ConvertBinaryToString(BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8, hash);
    }
```

The last line, converting the buffer back to a string doesn't work. I get this exception:

No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page.

How can I convert the buffer back into a string?

Comment: `string` is UTF-16LE, yet you are requesting `BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8`. I don't know, what sort of conversion the language projection implements in this case, nor why you are requesting UTF-8 to begin with.

Comment: I have to admit, I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security, cryptographic hashes are very fast. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2` (aka `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`), `password_hash`/`password_verify`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force. Protecting your users is important, please use secure password methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming, that you want to get the hashed password in a base64-format, because you did that in your .net example.
To get this, change:

```
CryptographicBuffer.ConvertBinaryToString(BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8, hash);
```

to:

```
CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(hash);
```

So the complete method looks like this:

```
public string GetHashedPassword(string password, string salt)
        {

            IBuffer input = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(password + salt, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
            var hashAlgorithm = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithmNames.Sha256);
            var hash = hashAlgorithm.HashData(input);

            return CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(hash);
        }
```

Comment: Note that this is an insecure method of hashing a password and should not be used, It puts users at risk.